# How to hide text of shortcuts in toolbar on system bar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, desktop-toolbar

I often use shortcut toolbar in my PC. But recently when I re-add the toolbar as below snapshoot, the shortcuts are displayed also with text in addition to icons.

I just want the old icon-only display mode. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to add that screenshot :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yes thank you. I've update my snapshoots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-lock the Taskbar, then right-click your toolbar and un-check "Show Text".  When you're done, you can lock the Taskbar again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wish we could up-vote edits.  Thanks @Nam for adding screenshots.

Comment: So happy to hear this @Iszy ^^